# How to check getElementsByClassName's position?

Tags: javascript, arrays, getelementsbyclassname

I have a product list (`li` elements) with custom titles and buttons. In addition there is also a popup form which is triggered by clicking any of the buttons.

There are as many  *Click me!* buttons, as many titles, but all of them trigger the same pop-up.

What I want to achieve is that form input element's value of the popup form is taken from a specific title according to the position of the button. So, if I click the *Click me!* under the button *Second title*, the input element value will be filled with *Second title*.

This is what I figured out, but somehow it won't work. I get the same value. Could someone help me to find the problem?

Thanks in advance!

```js
var title = document.getElementsByClassName('title');
var titleText;
var i;      
for (i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
  titleText = title[i].innerText;
  console.log("Name: " + titleText + ", position: " + i);
}
document.getElementById('inserthere').value = titleText;
```

```html
<ul class="products-list">
<li class="product">
<h2 class="title">First title</h2>
<a class="button" href="#">Click me!</a>
</li>
<li class="product">
<h2 class="title">Second title</h2>
<a class="button" href="#">Click me!</a>
</li>
<li class="product">
<h2 class="title">Third title</h2>
<a class="button" href="#">Click me!</a>
</li>
<li class="product">
<h2 class="title">Fourth title</h2>
<a class="button" href="#">Click me!</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="popup">
<input type="text" id="inserthere" value="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the text by taking the clicked element, retrieve the sibling (via the parent element), pick up its text and then display that:

```js
// We use event delegation, by picking up the bubbled-up click event 
//   in the container element. This way we only to bind only one click handler 
document.querySelector(".products-list").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains("button")) { // The click was on a button class
        // Go to the button's parent and find the title underneath it:
        document.getElementById("inserthere").value = 
            e.target.parentNode.querySelector(".title").textContent;
    }
});
```

```html
<ul class="products-list">
    <li class="product">
        <h2 class="title">First title</h2>
        <a class="button" href="#">Click me!</a>
    </li>
    <li class="product">
        <h2 class="title">Second title</h2>
        <a class="button" href="#">Click me!</a>
    </li>
    <li class="product">
        <h2 class="title">Third title</h2>
        <a class="button" href="#">Click me!</a>
    </li>
    <li class="product">
        <h2 class="title">Fourth title</h2>
        <a class="button" href="#">Click me!</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div class="popup">
    <input type="text" id="inserthere" value="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, [don't use `.getElementsByClassName()` - ever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474). And, in this case you don't even need to get all the elements. Just handle the click event at the `ul` level because all events will "bubble" up to their ancestor. Handling events this way is called ["event delegation"](https://javascript.info/event-delegation).

But, you are also using HTML incorrectly.

- `a` elements are for navigation, not for something that can trigger
  JavaScript. Nearly all elements support a `click` event, so use a
  `span` and style it to look like a hyperlink.
- Don't use headings (`h1`...`h6`) because of how they look. They are
  meant to denote the beginning of a section or sub-section. Again,
  choose a better element and style it the way you'd like.
- Don't use an `input` element for output. Use a placeholder like a
  `span` instead.

See comments inline:

```js
let output = document.getElementById("out");

// Set up the event handler on the common ancestor of all the elements that will
// be clicked and handle the click event there ("event delegation")
document.querySelector(".products-list").addEventListener("click", function(event){
  
  // You can get a reference to the actual element that the event was triggered on
  // through the event object reference that was passed into the event handler
  if(event.target.classList.contains("button")){
    // Now just get the text of the previous sibling that is an element
    output.textContent = event.target.previousElementSibling.textContent;
  }

});
```

```css
.title { font-weight:bold; font-size:1.1em; }
.button { color:blue; cursor:pointer; text-decoration:underline; }
#out { width:10em; height:1em; border:1px solid #808080; }
```

```html
<ul class="products-list">
  <li class="product">
    <div class="title">First title</div>
    <span class="button">Click me!</span>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <div class="title">Second title</div>
    <span class="button">Click me!</span>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <div class="title">Third title</div>
    <span class="button">Click me!</span>
  </li>
  <li class="product">
    <div class="title">Fourth title</div>
    <span class="button">Click me!</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="popup">
  <div id="out"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If in case you are interested with the order of the texts, as you used i in your code, you may use `forEach( (value, index) => {...} )`:

```js
const inserthere = document.getElementById('inserthere');

[...document.getElementsByClassName('button')].forEach( (button, i) => 
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
       let titleText = event.target.previousElementSibling.innerText;
       inserthere.value = titleText;
       console.log("Name: " + titleText + ", position: " + i);
    })
)
```

```html
<ul class="products-list">
<li class="product">
<h2 class="title">First title</h2>
<a class="button" href="#">Click me!</a>
</li>
<li class="product">
<h2 class="title">Second title</h2>
<a class="button" href="#">Click me!</a>
</li>
<li class="product">
<h2 class="title">Third title</h2>
<a class="button" href="#">Click me!</a>
</li>
<li class="product">
<h2 class="title">Fourth title</h2>
<a class="button" href="#">Click me!</a>
</li>
</ul>
<div class="popup">
<input type="text" id="inserthere" value="">
</div>
<br><br>
```